# Build of project fails on Visual Studio Team Services - missing lock file

Tags: build, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I am trying to configure CI for my team project, however, my build doesn't get past the first library project. It is complaining about missing the lock file. I have configured nugget to restore but that doesn't seem to create the lock file. Git ignores the lock file so it is not put in repository.

```
   Summary
| Build
3 error(s), 0 warning(s) 
Build - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(241):Project Core does not have a lock file.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(241):Project Core does not have a lock file.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
| Finalize build
0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Does anyone know how to force build to create the lock file?

My solution is an ASP.NET Core RC2 website. It builds fine on VS 2015. Microsoft announce ASP.NET Core last week so it should be on the build servers, or do I have to create my own build server?

Here is the contents of my project.json file for the Core Library:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "NodaTime": "2.0.0-alpha20160523"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0-rc2-24027"
      },
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what is installed on the Hosted Build servers: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/hosted-pool#software. Given that it's still running Visual Studio Update 2, I don't expect it to have ASP.NET Core RC2 on it yet.

Comment: I haven't tried VS Team Services but I believe this basically means that nothing ran `dotnet restore`.

Comment: I just updated my dev box to VS 2015, Update 3 yesterday. My builds worked on Update 2. After looking at the list referenced by @jessehouwing, I can see that Core is not mentioned at all. Perhaps that is why it isn't creating the lock file. I'll either have to wait for MS to include on hosted build server or create my own.

Comment: Which Asp.Net Core SDK version are you using? The version installed on Hosted Build Agent is RC2 Preview1 (1.0.0-preview1-002702).

Comment: I am using RC2 Preview 1. I am also using Visual Studio Update 3 on my dev box. When I checked, that version was not on the hosted build. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Did you follow the steps here:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure to create the build definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a new build step to your build definition.

Add a 'Command Line' task as step 1 of your build definition.

The settings for this task are:

Tool:        dotnet

Arguments:   restore

You can also speed this up a little by adding the following variable to your build definition:
DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE = true

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out from the comments left by @jessehouwing, but he did not leave an answer that I could mark. Perhaps I should have answered my own question, but since you gave the answered I figured out, I will mark yours as the answer.